# Angular - Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

Stuck with

```
error = Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

However, an actual array with 8 objects does come through from the server to the client.
Says so in the console:

```
    {state: "success-all", message: Array(8)}
    state: "success-all"
    message: Array(8)
    0: {ProductID: 567618, ProductName: "Milk", CategoryID: 111, Price: 5, Picture: "4.bp.blogspot.com/-5gXei54TIzE/Va2qDgaoPeI/AAAAAAAAAsM/XsqhQCKI53E/s1600/a%2Bcarton%2Bof%2Bmilk.jpg"}
    1: {ProductID: 567619, ProductName: "Eggs", CategoryID: 111, Price: 12, Picture: "https://www.cacklehatchery.com/media/catalog/produ…df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/w/h/whiteegg1.jpg"}
    2: {ProductID: 567621, ProductName: "Apple", CategoryID: 222, Price: 2, Picture: "https://healthjade.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/apple-fruit.jpg"}
    3: {ProductID: 567622, ProductName: "Carrot", CategoryID: 222, Price: 1, Picture: "https://images.wagwalkingweb.com/media/articles/dog/carrots-allergies/carrots-allergies.jpg"}
    4: {ProductID: 567624, ProductName: "Beaf", CategoryID: 333, Price: 25, Picture: "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/raw-beaf-steaks-white-background-60591511.jpg
    ↵"}
    5: {ProductID: 567626, ProductName: "Fish", CategoryID: 333, Price: 20, Picture: "dreamicus.com/data/salmon/salmon-02.jpg
    ↵"}
    6: {ProductID: 567628, ProductName: "Bottled Water", CategoryID: 444, Price: 8, Picture: "https://banner2.kisspng.com/20171207/b5e/mineral-w…bottles-5a29c05b9a6cd4.1467465915126856596325.jpg"}
    7: {ProductID: 567630, ProductName: "Red Wine", CategoryID: 444, Price: 35, Picture: "https://theathleticrider.com/wp-content/uploads/si…7/2013/12/Kozzi-red_wine_and_grapes-3264x4896.jpg"}
    length: 8
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let i of products">
    <h6>{{i.ProductID}}</h6>
    <h6>{{i.ProductName}}</h6>
    <h6>{{i.price}}</h6>
    <h6>{{i.picture}}</h6>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { httpService } from '../http.services';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-store',
      templateUrl: './store.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./store.component.css']
    })

    export class StoreComponent implements OnInit {
      public products

      constructor(public HttpService:httpService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.HttpService.getProducts().subscribe(
            res=>{
                console.log(res)
                this.products = res
              },
            err=>console.log(err)
        )
    }

    }
```

**Http.service.TS:**

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


    //Links frontend to backend


    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
      })
      export class httpService {

        constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

        public newUser(user) {
          console.log("Post Works")
          return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/register', user)
        }

        public getProducts() {
          console.log("Store works")
          return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/store')
      }

    }
```

I have tried this code with Mongo DB and it worked. The current DB is sql. does that make a difference?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just look at what you get from the server. It's not an array. It's an object. And this object has a `message` property, which is an array.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { httpService } from '../http.services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-store',
  templateUrl: './store.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./store.component.css']
})

export class StoreComponent implements OnInit {
  public products = []; // initialise as []

  constructor(public HttpService:httpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.HttpService.getProducts().subscribe(
        res=>{
            console.log(res)
            this.products = res.message; // change here
          },
        err=>console.log(err)
    )
}

}
```

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.HttpService.getProducts().subscribe(
        res=>{
            console.log(res)
            this.products = res.message; // change here
          },
        err=>console.log(err)
    )
}

}


I get an error on the res.message; // change here